# Can I specify a control for each type of object?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have an `ObservableCollection` of `Fruit`.

```
public ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruit {get; set;}
```

Fruit is bound to a `UserControl` (that parents a `Canvas`) called FruitContainer.

```
fruitContainer.ItemsSource = Fruit;
```

However, there are subclasses of `Fruit`.

```
public class Apple : Fruit { ... }
public class Banana : Fruit { ... }
public class Strawberry : Fruit { ... }
```

And these are the actual contents of the `ObservableCollection`. They also have their own correlating `UserControl`, `AppleControl`, `BananaControl`, etc.

My question is, can I setup a Template (or something else) on FruitContainer so that each object type in `ItemsSource` will automatically add it's own `UserControl`? Like a custom `ListBox` item, but everyone has their own item depending on their type...

Comment: Feel free to come visit us in the [WPF Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf), if you want someone to bounce questions like these off of...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you could define a `DataTemplate` per type:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="fruitContainer">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Banana}">
            <local:BananaUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Apple}">
            <local:AppleUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: add ItemsSource="{Binding Fruit}" to the ItemsControl

Comment: The OP seems to set the ItemsSource property programmatically. Also, this has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Data template? You can specify target type on data template.

```
 <DataTemplate  x:Key="SomeKey" TargetType="{x:Type  local:Apple }">
                template goes here
 </DataTemplate>
```